# Ubuntu 17.10 freezing on suspend and won't shutdown

Tags: suspend, 17.10

Hello i'm using ubuntu 17.10 on a lenovo ideapad 110s and anytime the system suspends it freezes on the lock screen and if I try to to shutdown the computer it stays on the shutdown screen. Holding down the power button is the only way I can shut it down. I've used previous versions of ubuntu on this laptop and haven't had any troubles.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [this issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1724317). You might want to add to the comments there.